# RSA privatekey being viewed as string cannot use decrypt function

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I'm creating a program for an assignment where we have to create a nounce encrypt it using RSA over tcp socket connections then decrypt that nounce to use as the key for DES. However when i try to decrypt the nounce using the private key i get an error saying str object doesn't have attribute decrypt

I had previously created a program that encrypts and decrypts something using RSA but that was done in the same program. Because i was using that as a guideline i thought the problem was with the nounce and tried using ast.literal_eval but got the same error

Makes the keys

```
#MakeKeys
rsaKey = RSA.generate(1024)
privKey = rsaKey.exportKey(format='PEM')
pubKey = rsaKey.publickey().exportKey(format='PEM')
```

the public key is written to a file so that the other program can access it

```
#recieve nounce
ennounce = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
print(ennounce)
nounce = privKey.decrypt(ennounce)
```

In the previous program this `privKey.decrypt(encrypted thing)` line worked fine so why am i getting an error here

Comment: Your `privKey` is an export to PEM format, but you need to use the original.

Comment: @Justice_Lords can you explain you explain why that might be the case, between assignment and attempted encryption privKey is not touched

Comment: @KlausD. I'm sorry i don't understand what exactly would be the original here

Comment: @Justice_Lords Okay i managed to fix it thanks, I didn't think that when generating the key it wouldn't give me an actual RSA key object